# Is there a issue with using NetworkX from multiple processes on different graphs?

Tags: networkx

If each process creates its own nx.Graph() and adds/removes nodes/edges to it, is there any reason for them to collide? I am noticing some weird phenomenoms and trying to debug them.

The general problem is that I am dumping a single graph as an edge list, and recreating it from a subset in each process into a new graph. for some reason those new graphs are missing edges.

**EDIT:**

I think I found the part of code which causes the problems for me, the question is whether the following is the intended behaviour of NetworkX or not:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> g = nx.Graph()
>>> g.add_path([0,1,2,3])
>>> g.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> g.edges()
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> g[1][0]
{}
>>> g[0][1] = {"test":1}
>>> g.edges(data=True)
[(0, 1, {'test': 1}), (1, 2, {}), (2, 3, {})]
>>> g[1][0]
{}
>>> g[0][1]
{'test': 1}
>>>
```

Since the graph is a undirectional one I would expect the edge data to appear both regardless to the nodes id in the request, is that an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 0):

In general there should be no issue with multiple processes as long as they each have their own Graph() object.

EDIT:

In your case you are explicitly assigning data to the internal NetworkX Graph structure with the line

```
>>> g[0][1] = {"test":1}
```

While that is technically allowed it breaks the API and data structure.  You should instead use

```
>>> g.add_edge(0,1,test=1)
```

which won't add a new edge here, only a new attribute.  Doing it that way assigns the data to g[0][1] and g[1][0] correctly.